# resultCode has value -1 after a buttonpress and finish() but 0 after backbutton pressed even with same code in corresponding functions

Tags: java, android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have a RecyclerView with its Adapter.class in a separate file but the onClickListener in the adapter starts the second Activity just fine with startActivityForResult. When I have the users input I want the app to send back the data to the first Activity which only works when the user uses a button I provided, but not when he uses the backbutton even when it runs the same code in the corresponding functions.

i copied the exact same code from the button to onBackPressed, onPause and onDestroy but on Destroy gets run too late, and the other two lead to resultCode being 0 and data being null in Activity 1. I have changed setResult and its arguments to all possible variants I found(RESULT_OK+Intent, Activity.RESULT_OK+Intent and just RESULT_OK).

back = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                back.putExtra("ANSWER", answer.getText().toString());
                back.putExtra("QUESTION_ID", questionId);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, back);
                finish();
            }
         });
@Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        back.putExtra("ANSWER", answer.getText().toString());
        back.putExtra("QUESTION_ID", questionId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, back);
     }
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        back.putExtra("ANSWER", answer.getText().toString());
        back.putExtra("QUESTION_ID", questionId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, back);
    }
```

if I use the Button it passes the data and sets the resultCode to -1 just fine but when I don't use the button but the backbutton resultCode = 0 and data in on ActivityResult is null. I don't know what makes the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set result before `onBackPressed` of superclass calling:

```java
     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
        back.putExtra("ANSWER", answer.getText().toString());
        back.putExtra("QUESTION_ID", questionId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, back);
        super.onBackPressed();
     }
```

Comment: thanks that helped a lot, can you tell me what this does? the resultCode in MainActivity is now -1, data is still null though, but now I have a new hint to continue on it

Comment: okay it actually solved all my problems, thanks again. can you explain my mistake to me nevertheless?

Comment: @DennisSimon, the internal implementation of `onBackPressed` includes `finish()` statement. So, you should set result **before** calling it.

Comment: Best wishes, and accept the answer please, if it heally helps